Is internal energy dependent on the acceleration of the system?
Consider an ideal gas confined in an adiabatic container.
We know that internal energy does not depend on the velocity of a uniformly moving system, because relative to the walls of the container, the effect of uniform motion is cancelled, hence pressure does not depend on the uniform motion and therefore the temperature, by $PV=nRT$. As internal energy for this case is $\frac{f(nRT)}{2}$ [derived from statistical mechanics], it does not depend on the uniform motion
But if the container is accelerating, the gas molecules must feel an additional force from the wall that is normal to the direction of acceleration. Hence the pressure exerted on that wall increases. In that case, how are the calculations to find internal energy performed, because different pressure is exerted on different walls?

This question is similar to: Internal energy of a gas inside a moving box. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

In order for the internal energy of the ideal gas in an adiabatic container to change, work must be done on the gas by its surroundings as heat is excluded. For a closed system that work is generally boundary work (expansion or contraction of the container walls). If the adiabatic enclosure is rigid, then boundary work does not apply. Presumably there is no shaft penetrating the enclosure such that stirrer (paddle) work is not possible.
If the container of gas is accelerating, this means there is a net external force applied to the container. But that force does not alter the volume of the gas. The resulting acceleration can cause pressure and temperature gradients within the gas because part of the gas is compressed at one end and expanded at the other due to its inertia. While this will cause spatial variations of the internal energy in the container, the total internal energy should remain the same.
On the other hand, the total mechanical energy (KE + PE) of the container of gas as a whole with respect to an external (to the container) frame of reference can change due to its motion and/or position with respect to that frame of reference.
Hope this helps.

Internal energy is defined as the total energy possessed by the particles only due to relative motion and configuration that's why if for example you take a box full of gas initially at rest with internal energy $U$ and you give it some kinetic energy $K$ its internal energy wouldn't increase.
in the case of accelerating that box the gas would clump on the back of the box, reducing the relative distances between the particles which would mean it reduces the relative potential energies of the particles therefore a decrease in the potential component of the internal energy $\Delta U_{p}<0$ but it would also increase the particles relative velocities (relative to the box) as there would be an increase in pressure and as the rms values of particles velocities are linked with pressure by:
$P$ $= \frac{1}{3} \rho C_{rms}^{2}$
this would mean there is a net increase in the kinetic component of internal energy making the net change in internal energy $\Delta U = 0$
but if we talk about an ideal gas $U_{p}$ is taken to be $0$ so there would be a net increase in the internal energy of the gas, this happens because we did work in moving the gas and that work done by us was transmitted to the gas and increased its internal energy also taking the whole process to be adiabatic, with the container having adiabatic walls.

Ideal gases don't have a potential component to the internal energy right? I am not getting that bit.

@SemiballisticS yes, right ideal gasses are those theoretical gasses whose potential component of internal energy is taken to be $0$ , though i was talking about in a more general manner for the real gasses.

In the presence of acceleration global pressure is ill-defined. As an illustration, think of Earth atmosphere, where different sections experience different pressure. So, strictly speaking, one cannot expect to have an equation of motion with a single parameter $P$ for the entire system. This is OK; most solids also don't have a simple gas-like equation of state $f(P,V,T)=0$. As a substitute, if the gradient of local pressure is small on inter-atomic length-scales, you can do the usual thing: (mentally) divide the system into slices with well-defined local pressure and describe each with the usual equation state for that gas.
I forgot that the original question was regarding the internal energy. Answer: if we assume that the gas in question is ideal, then its internal energy is independent of $P$. Therefore, the total internal energy of the system (which by definition excludes the kinetic energy of the center of mass) is not changed as compared to the non-accelerated one. If the gas non-ideal, then generally speaking the internal energy does depend on $P$, and hence the overall acceleration does affect $U$.
